# Is there a function in PHP (or ImageMagick) resize image to best cover?

Tags: php, image-resizing

I thought it was a simple question but I was surprised that there are no solution on Google. Sorry if I missed some results. Is there a way to resize an image to best covers an area instead of best fit without calculating the width height and position by myself?

For best covers, I mean something like `background-size: cover;` in CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing built-in for this purpose. However, you may be able to find a package which can do this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer although this is a disappointing one. Let me wait a  bit before I marking this as a correct answer.

Comment: The answer from `cseelus` is correct. Or you can specify -gravity northwest if you want to pin the top left corner. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/#cut

Comment: I do not think PHP Imagick can do this directly. I think you will need to compute the scale factor for the width and then again for the height and then pick the correct one to over-fill the desired opposite dimension. Then crop.

Answer (score 3):

Using ImageMagick for something that matches CSS `background-size: cover` you could do as follows (say your target format is a square, of 300 pixels width and height):

```
 convert sourcimage.jpg -resize 300x300^ -gravity center -extent 300x300 targetimage.jpg
```

1. `resize` the smaller image side via `^` and let the larger side get bigger than 300 pixels
2. Set `gravity` to `center`
3. And finally `extent` to cut the resized image to the exact size you wanted (cutting off the excess from step 1)